# Android: When to use layout_margin, when to use weightSum?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am trying to achieve the following layout on my Android app:

[image]

As you can see I want a central login box taking about 70% of the width. I believe there are basically two approaches to achieve this:

**1.** Create a Linear or Relative layout for the login box, and add layoutMargin both on the left and right sides.

**2.** Create a wrapper LinearLayout with weightSum="1", and then place the RelativeLayout inside it with layout_width="0dp" and layout_weight="0.7".

Using the first approach the XML would look like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo"  
         />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"         
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#999999"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
         >
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"           
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:hint="@string/email" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"            
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:hint="@string/password" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:text="@string/login"/>


    </LinearLayout>     


</LinearLayout>
```

The second approach would just have a wrapper LinearLayout on top of the current one, with weightSum="1", and the internal layout would get a layout_weight="0.7" attribute.

Which one do you think is the best approach? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A rather simple way would be use a linear layout inside a relative layout. Then use layout_centerInParent and set it to "true". Once that is done you can set your margin to what ever you would like (I used 30 dp). Here is an example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="50" >

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:inputType="numberPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/editText2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Of course, if you wanted the width of the log in box to be exactly 70 percent of the width of the screen, you could do it programmatically.

Comment: That's pretty much the approach n. 1 I mentioned in my question isn't it?

Comment: I would say yes with an important note. You suggested for the parent layout a relative or linear layout. I choose relative, because that allowed me to use the layout_centerInParent parameter. On that was done it's trivial to set the margin to what ever you think looks good.

Comment: Even with linear this would work though. You would just need to android:gravity="center" instead.

Comment: I think that is correct. Now that I think about it, you might want to consider switching what I have above to use a frame layout instead of the relative layout. It should accomplish that same look but be less expensive to process and therefore perform better. Although, in the context of your app it may not matter.

Answer (score 0):

There's a 3d alternative, create the login box in a LinearLayout/RelativeLayout, and then align it center horizontally.

Comment: But if I do that without using margins the login box will take the whole width, which is not what I want. And if I use width="wrap_content" on the login box I will need to set a fixed width for the EditTexts.

Comment: From my perspective in this case is not necessary margins, just let the login box `layout_width="wrap_content"` (and layout_height also), and it will take as much space as it needs.

Comment: But then how would you accomplish to have the EditTexts inside the login box with the same width?

Comment: Linear layout with  android:gravity="center"

Comment: That would just center the EditTexts, but their size would still be variable if I used layout_width="wrap_content" on them.